# Sending upload progress from S3 Boto3 to Angular Frontend

Tags: python, django, angular, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using Django to upload files to AWS S3 using Boto3. I have been successful in doing this, but I wonder how I can get the AWS S3 upload progress, provided by Boto3 via a callback, sent over to the frontend. I am using the code similar to the following to upload using Boto3:

```
s3.upload_file("filename.txt", AWS_BUCKET_NAME, "key", Callback=ProgressPercentage("filename.txt"))
```

And in turn using the callback example provided by the Boto3 docs:

```
import os
import sys
import threading

class ProgressPercentage(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename
        self._size = float(os.path.getsize(filename))
        self._seen_so_far = 0
        self._lock = threading.Lock()

    def __call__(self, bytes_amount):
        # To simplify, assume this is hooked up to a single filename
        with self._lock:
            self._seen_so_far += bytes_amount
            percentage = (self._seen_so_far / self._size) * 100
            sys.stdout.write(
                "\r%s  %s / %s  (%.2f%%)" % (
                    self._filename, self._seen_so_far, self._size,
                    percentage))
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

But instead of passing the output to `sys.stdout.write` I want to somehow get it over to the frontend (specifically, to an Angular client). Any ideas on how I do this?

If I do print the output of the above callback I get the following in the Django console:

```
filename.txt 262144 / 3457480.0 (7.58%)
filename.txt 524288 / 3457480.0 (15.16%)
filename.txt 786432 / 3457480.0 (22.75%)
...
```

This output would be useful for me on the frontend.

Comment: hey, found any solution?